# What advantages/disadvantages do MSTest and NUnit have compared to each other?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, comparison, mstest

Since Microsoft created MSTest, I've been using it for unit testing. I never really used NUnit, and I just didn't like the need to have yet another tool installed on my dev box. I've only used the basic features of MSTest so far, and they have satisfied my needs, and I don't really know anything about NUnit.

Could someone list out some of the disadvantages and advantages of using MSTest and NUnit compared to each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a nice blog which lists out some differences between MSTest and NUnit http://blogs.msdn.com/nnaderi/archive/2007/02/01/mstest-vs-nunit-frameworks.aspx

And this link here compares even more unit testing frameworks http://www.codeplex.com/xunit/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Comparisons

cheers

Comment: The given links are dead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more recent review of Nunit, Mstest for Visual Studio: 
http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/mstest-vs-nunit-with-visual-studio-2010-tdd/

Answer (score 1):

For .net core:

> NUnit was not fully compatible with .NET Core 2 at the time

https://dev.to/hatsrumandcode/net-core-2-why-xunit-and-not-nunit-or-mstest--aei

Some new features in xUnit:

https://dev.to/franndotexe/mstest-v2---new-old-kid-on-the-block